# How to run some apps with proxy in university/colleges?

Tags: networking, proxy

(Win 10)
Currently I run my internet on my college LAN connection that has a proxy. It requires some id  like 1.2.3.4.... and port like 1234 and user id like 1234abcd and password. So whenever I try to update windows via update and Recovery or try to install apps from Windows app store, I can't. So is there anyway to configure these apps to work with thisproxy and authentication like some global internet access on my pc via a intermediater that has all the credential stored??

Comment: Windows update cannot be configured to use a proxy. you would have to use a virtual network card-based solution like a Layer 2 VPN, which forces all traffic through the VPN tunnel.

Comment: @FrankThomas can you explain how to do that?

Comment: well, ultimately, your best bet is to look for any documentation provided by your college, as they have most certainly allowed a pathway for windows to update. For a VPN, you have to obtain a remote endpoint somehow (rent one, set one up at home, etc), and connect to it with a utility like the Cisco VPN client, and be sure to disable "Split Tunneling". that way all traffic outbound will go through the VPN to the remote endpoint, and from there to MS. This of course assumes that your school allows VPN out, but they control everything anyway.

Comment: @FrankThomas nope there's no documentation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Software like Proxifier and CCProxy worked, in case someone has same problem as me.

Answer (score 1):

If you have the correct proxy settings in Internet Explorer, you can import those to WinHTTP with the following command in an [elevated command prompt](http://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/2790-elevated-command-prompt-open-windows-10-a.html):

`netsh winhttp import proxy source=ie`

Or you can set the proxy manually with:

`netsh winhttp set proxy MYPROXYSERVER:PORT`